# Refreshing Gridview in Jquerymobile after update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've created a page with a grid block consists of buttons using "jquery-mobile" plugin. The buttons inside the grid are created dynamically at run time. After a post back call the old values still remain. I want to refresh the grid with new values after update.

Here is the code.

Html:

```
<div id="chapter_div" data-role="page" data-content-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Chapter Chooser</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-grid-d" id="show_chapter_number"> 
    </div>                  
</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery code:

```
function showChapter(book_id) {

           var chapter_count=" ";
           var menu = " ";

           var html = " ";
           var row_count = 1;
           var row_block_id = 'a';

           chapter_count = getChapterCount(book_id);

           for (itr = 1; itr <= chapter_count; itr++) {

             switch(row_count) {
                    case 1:
                    row_block_id = 'a';
                    row_count++;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    row_block_id = 'b';
                    row_count++;
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    row_block_id = 'c';
                    row_count++;
                    break;
                    case 4:
                    row_block_id = 'd';
                    row_count++;
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    row_block_id = 'e';
                    row_count=1;
                    break;

                }

                html += "<div class=\"ui-block-"+row_block_id+"\"><button onclick=\"javascript:showVerse(" + book_id + ",\'" + itr + "\');\" class=\"ui-bar ui-bar-c\" style=\"width:70px\">" + itr + "</button></div>";

            }               

            var grid_chapter = $('#show_chapter_number');

            grid_chapter.append(html);

            $.mobile.changePage("#chapter_div", {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});              

            **grid_chapter.content("refresh");**

        }
```

What should I do to refresh the items in the grid or in the content after a postback?

How should I change this line of the code: `grid_chapter.content("refresh");` to make it work properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`trigger("create")`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) method:

```
grid_chapter.append(html).trigger("create");
```

Comment: could you please vote up my question, so that i could gain enough reputation to vote up your answer.

Comment: sorry Peterm :(.it;s not working. really sorry. i misunderstood that it has worked correctly.

Comment: @Karthi What exactly is not working? Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/Z9nL4/) that shows that elements have been enhanced by jQM after being dynamically added. Try to remove `trigger("create")` and see what you'll get.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort sir. I explain you the exact scenario of my code block. It's book,chapter,verse chooser. First on clicking the menu icon, a page containing the names of the books in form of grid buttons will appear. on selecting a book, the chapter numbers of the corresponding book will appear in the next dialog or page in the form of grid buttons. After selecting the chapter number next page containing the grid buttons of the verse number should appear. the verse numbers of each chapter will change, as well as the chapters of each book.

Comment: when selecting book2 having 10 chapters, the "chapter chooser" page will consists of 10 buttons. If i go back and choose other book again, for ex. choosing book3 containing 15 chapters, the chapter number page  still has the old data in it. could not able to refresh it. same problem for the "verse chooser" page as well. Tried trigger("create"). It fails to produce the result.

Comment: @Karthi Well your original question doesnt't contain this information and appropriate code associated with it (e.g. how you navigate from page to page, pass and return values from dialog). Now `trigger("create")` does exactly what it should (enhance dynamically added content) and what it seemed you asked in your question. You might want to consider update your question and/or to ask additional question(s).